# LINQ Case statement within Count

Tags: sql, linq, count, case

Can you help me translate this sql into Linq please:

```
select 
    count(case when t.TypeID = 1 then t.TypeID end) as a,
    count(case when t.TypeID = 2 then t.TypeID end) as b,
    count(case when t.TypeID = 3 then t.TypeID end) as c
from myTable t
```

I've searched the internet and found some similar sql but nothing that fits this scenario.  Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
var query = new
            {
              a = (context.MyTable.Where(t => t.TypeID == 1).Count(),
              b = (context.MyTable.Where(t => t.TypeID == 2).Count(),
              c = (context.MyTable.Where(t => t.TypeID == 3).Count(),
            }
```

Edit - If you want it all in one query you could do this:

```
var query = from x in context.MyTable
            group x by 1 into xg
            select new
            {
              a = xg.Where(t => t.TypeID == 1).Count(),
              b = xg.Where(t => t.TypeID == 2).Count(),
              c = xg.Where(t => t.TypeID == 3).Count(),
            };
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, it had occurred to me just after i posted that it would be easier to use extension methods.  Thanks... i'll mark it as the answer as soon as it'll let me